# Load local files on Chrome-os

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-os

I am trying to create a JavaScript pacman game, but whenever I try and load my script files or images, I get the error:

[image]
The browser I'm using is chrome, and the files are stored in the same directory. I am running CHROME OS, so I can't just go into files and edit an existing flag.
Same for the images, except the file name is different.
Does anyone know why I am getting an error `Access Denied`, or how I could test the files?
The files are loaded using this format

```
<script src="Scripts/gamescript.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="game" id="game">
        <img src="/Images/ghosts/red.png" />
    </div>
</body>
```

Per request, here is my file tree

```
/Javascript_Pacman_Game/
    index.html
    /Styles/
        stylesheet.css
    /Scripts/
        gamescript.js
        myCustomLibrary.js
        setInterval.js
    /Images/
        /Ghosts/
            red.png
            blue.png
            pink.png
            orange.png
            scared.png
        /GameElements/
            board.jpg
            bloop.png
            superBloop.png
```

The problem isn't spelling or file permissions, and I can't run a local host because of Chrome-OS.

Comment: That would be your browser's security. So you are running off of the file system. What browser are you using?

Comment: hard to say with the information you have given us, possibly some kind of permissions issue, I would highly recommend using WAMP, MAMP or something similar, it will help resolve these and other issues down the line

Comment: @epascarello I'm using chrome

Comment: @wyatt can you try to run it with firefox or some other browser?

Comment: @kpblc At the moment on my stupid little chromebook by Acer, but i'm sure if it's a security thing It won't work in firefox, or IE.

Comment: @wyatt See http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

Comment: @wyatt tipicaly it's ok, when you run script from saved page. just try to download any slider for example http://www.jssor.com/download-bootstrap-carousel-slider-example.html  if it's work fine, problem with something else

Comment: @wyatt can you describe where is you index.html and there is located script. for example you have folder MyProject and inside this folder index.html, script.js style,css.

Comment: @kpblc Added my file tree

Comment: @wyatt error in console indicate to gamescript.js and i didn't noticed such file in you files tree. maybe you just rename some js file and then forgot to change it's name in script src on page

Comment: @kpblc Ijust named it wrong in  the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try installing [Web server for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb/related?hl=en), telling it to serve files from your `/Javascript_Pacman_Game` folder, and testing your app at http://127.0.0.1:8887/

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect. Here's +75 rep!

Answer (score 2):

If you have to handle this from chromium OS (specially with dual boot cloud ready), follow the steps

**Step 1:**
Go to the shell prompt Ctrl + Alt + T on shell open the chrome_dev.conf

```
$ sudo vi /etc/chrome_dev.conf
```

The sudo default password would be 'chrome', The file may be write protected follow these steps incase if you stuck in step 1

```
$ sudo cp /etc/chrome_dev.conf /usr/local
$ sudo mount --bind /usr/local/chrome_dev.conf /etc/chrome_dev.conf
$ sudo vi /etc/chrome_dev.conf
```

**Step 2:**
Once you open up the file write `--allow-file-access-from-files` on top of the file

**Step 3:**
Restart the UI (if you are using windows dual boot press CTRL + ALT + F2) from dev shell

```
$ sudo restart ui
```

Once its restart the changes will get affect in chromium OS chrome, to check type chrome://gpu on your chrome browser

Under command line Argument you can find argument options.

Answer (score 1):

You really should be running a local server. Apache, IIS, etc. Than you can run off localhost and have no issues.

BUT if you really want to run off the file system, you need to start up chrome to allow it.

You need to set  `--allow-file-access-from-files`

http://www.chrome-allow-file-access-from-file.com/

Comment: Any idea how to do this in Chrome OS?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/160245/how-do-i-make-the-google-chrome-flag-allow-file-access-from-files-permanent/192996#192996

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your permissions have been edited (or defaulted) to restrict your current user from accessing those files.

I managed to reproduce this error by creating the same file structure you have and then

`right clicking red.png > properties > security > edit...`

then denying access to this file from my current user. It seems that if you deny access via the directory you get a **File not found** error instead since the browser isn't even able to navigate to the directory in the first place.

Try checking your individual file permissions. If this is a default file permissions issue you may want to ask about how to fix that on a different forum.

Comment: Still using chrome-os, not windows, and this is the only user on the computer.

Comment: And also, I think the problem is with the browser, not the computer.

Answer (score 0):

The error is from your spelling, the first one you said

```
gamescript.js
```

and you called it as

```
script src="Scripts/gamscript.js"></script>
```

Check your spelling, you did not include "e"

Comment: Did you look at the error? I only misspelled it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Chrome Dev Editor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pnoffddplpippgcfjdhbmhkofpnaalpg) as your IDE, then you can just hit the run button in the top left.

You could also use this [Server](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb).

Answer (score -2):

javascript doesn't have access to the filesystem of a computer for security reasons do

```
 <script src="Scripts/gamescript.js"></script>
```

Comment: feb 3rd answered and question has been edited since, did you even look at the date ?