# How to use WebGL locally with no WebServer?

Tags: webgl

I am trying to make a games site you download to play the games, so I dont want anything to have to be downloaded except the website. I get the following error: It seems your browser does not support running Unity WebGL content from file:// urls. I have done some research and have found that you need to enable some stuff in chrome://flags but that di nothing. I haven't really been able to find anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run chrome with `--allow-file-access-from-files`.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I'm confused how would you do that one Chrome OS. I tried researching but couldn't find anything. Thanks for any further help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28301063/load-local-files-on-chrome-os

Comment: None of those worked in that link, I have sort of just abandoned the idea but thanks for the help!